# Can topological spaces arising as suspensions be characterised this way?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. The suspension of $X$ is the topological space $SX = X\times[0,1]/\sim$ where $(x_1, 0) \sim (x_2, 0)$ and $(x_1, 1)\sim (x_2, 1)$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$.

Let $p : X\times I \to SX$ be the projection. Note that $p(X\times[0, 1))$ and $p(X\times(0, 1])$ are open contractible subsets of $SX$ and their intersection is homotopy equivalent to $X$. Is the existence of such sets enough to characterise topological spaces which arise as suspensions? That is,

> If $Y$ is a connected topological space and $U, V \subset Y$ are open contractible subsets with $U\cup V = Y$ and $U\cap V$ homotopy equivalent to $X$, is $Y$ homotopy equivalent to $SX$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want strong homotopy equivalence then the answer is no. The [pseudocircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle) is a finite topological space with four points $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and open sets $X$, $\{a,b,c\}$, $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,b\}$, $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, and $\varnothing$. Then $X$ is the union of the two contractible open sets $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{a,b,d\}$ whose intersection is $\{a,b\}$ with the discrete topology, i.e. $S^0$. But $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to the suspension of $S^0$, AKA the circle. It is however weakly equivalent to it.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to this. Thanks for your answer. Do you know whether the property outlined above would ensure that $Y$ is weakly homotopy equivalent to $SX$?

Comment: Using Mayer-Vietoris, one can show $H_{k+1}(Y) \cong H_k(X)$ so $Y$ has the same homology groups as $\Sigma X$, and by Seifert-van Kampen, $Y$ is simply connected as is $\Sigma X$. However, it is not clear whether there is a weak homotopy equivalence between $\Sigma X$ and $Y$ (there seems to be no natural map, even if one assumes $U\cap V$ deformation retracts onto $X$).

Answer (score 2):

On p.247 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html) (T&G) we have

7.4.3 (Corollary) Let the space $X$ be the union of closed subspaces $X_1, X_2$ with intersection $X_0$ such that the inclusions $X_0 \to X_1, X_0 \to X_2$ are closed cofibrations. Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are contractible. Then $X$ is of the homotopy type of the suspension $SX_0$.

This is a Corollary of 7.4.3 (The gluing theorem), which first appeared in the 1968 (differently titled) edition of that book. I thought then, and still think,  that students should learn how to construct homotopy equivalences before they learned how  to show such did not exist.

See also this [mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96071/general-gluing-theorem-for-adjunction-spaces).

November 15: Actually there is a more precise result. Since $X_1$ is contractible, the identity map $X_0 \to X_0$ extends to a map of pairs $f:(CX_0,X_0) \to (X_1,X_0)$, where $CX_0$ is the cone on $X_0$. But the map $CX_0 \to X_1$ is a homotopy equivalence, since both are contractible. Now we can use 7.4.2 of T&G, and that $X_0 \to X_1$ is a cofibration,  to get that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence of pairs.